# How do you pass a multiline string to the openssl -config option as a bash argument instead of using a file?

Tags: bash

I was using this command

```bash
openssl req -new \
    -key $OUTPUT_DIRECTORY/certificate.pem \
    -reqexts SAN \
    -config <(cat ssl_default.conf \
        <(printf "\n[SAN]\nsubjectAltName=DNS:$HOSTNAME")) \
    -out $OUTPUT_DIRECTORY/certificate.csr
```

From what I understand, the `<(cat ssl_default.conf)` part will print the file `ssl_default.conf` and pass the contents to the `-config` argument. But I also include an extra `printf` command which adds an extra line to the file.

Instead of doing that, I want to just have the whole config as a string in bash so I can make multiple substitutions using bash variables before executing the `openssl` command.

I tried changing the code to look like this instead:

```bash
CONFIG=$(cat << EOF
[ req ]
default_bits       = 4096
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
req_extensions     = req_ext
prompt             = no

[ req_distinguished_name ]
commonName         = $HOSTNAME

[ req_ext ]
subjectAltName     = @alt_names

[SAN]
subjectAltName=DNS:$HOSTNAME
EOF
)

openssl req -new \
    -key $OUTPUT_DIRECTORY/certificate.pem \
    -reqexts SAN \
    -config <(echo -n "$CONFIG")
    -out $OUTPUT_DIRECTORY/certificate.csr
```

But the problem is I get the error message `line 57: -out: command not found`. Basically the `openssl` command is getting everything up until the `-out` part and then the `-out` part is being interpreted as the next command.

**How can I pass in this multiline string to the `-config` option properly?**

As a follow-up, why do I need to use `<(...)`? Why can't it just be `... -config "my config here" -out ...`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just forgot the `\` at the end of the line before the `-out`. Oops. Voting to close the question.